# How magento products that are added to wishlist can be filtered on the basis of category

Tags: magento

In magento, I want to filter the wishlist items of a logged in user on the basis of a catalog category.
Can anybody suggest me any solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Please check the image at the following url:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53435938/wishlist.png

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**  Not tested.  Little off-the-cuff action here.

```
// ID of the category you wish to filter by
$category_id = 35;

// Instantiate a category model and load it
$_category = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $category_id );

// Grab the wishlist collection
$_wishlistCollection = Mage::helper( 'wishlist' )->getWishlistItemCollection();

// Filter it by category as you would any normal collection
$_wishlistCollection->addCategoryFilter( $_category );
```

Then do your normal collection iteration.